# Please help me identify this scratched IC

Tags: identification, lithium-ion, charger

There are three 18650 lithium-ion batteries connected in series in a device and there is a charger circuit connected to it that has a scratched SOIC8 chip as cornerstone. Following is the circuit diagram:

[image: Extracted circuit]

Considering fully charged voltage of battery pack (3 × 4.2V = 12.6V) and the input voltage of 7 - 10V probably it is a voltage boost IC but specifically designed for charger circuits.

IC surface is scratched but not that deep to hide 1st pin indicator.

The only IC I found using Digikey.com filters is ADP3810 that doesn't match the pinout:
[image: ADP3810 pin config]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a MC34063A in StepUp regulator configuration.

https://www.ti.com/product/de-de/MC34063A

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO. I do appreciate every second of time you spent to answer my question. Danke schön.